# Clickonce Upgrade and application setting

Tags: clickonce, settings

We have a winform application deplyed using Clickonce which has a configuration file.

What we need is when there is an upgrade available, to merge the configuration in local machine with what is coming from the deplyoment.

Any ideas or experiences?

Answer (score 2):

There's an Upgrade method on Properties.Settings.Default that is supposed to do that if you call it before you access any of the settings.